# Memory Allocation for Python Datastructures

Tags: python, caching, memory, client-server

If I were to create a global variable in Python that holds a dictionary for caching data coming from the user, would this data be stored in the user's stack, or would it be stored in the server?

So, basically what I am trying to understand here is whether one global instance of a Python dictionary cache the data of all the users using the app or will there be an instance of that dictionary made for each person?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, when you fire up python and spawn an .exe whatever objects you have in that memory space will only be in that memory space.  They are not shared.

Comment: You are going to have to add more details to answer your question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So if I were hosting a Python program on a server that cached data in a dictionary, would every user's data be cached in only that one dictionary?